# Chatter Answer is not visible in prod org

Tags: chatter-answers

I have to work with "Chatter Answer". But I am not able to see the section of Chatter Answers in production org. I searched in the quick search box but didn't find there.[image].

But "Chatter Answer" is available in sandbox org. see the picture below.[image]

How to enable in prod org. Please help !

Answer (score 2):

This might be causing an issue.

**Starting in Summer ’16, Chatter Answers isn’t available in new orgs. Instead, you can use Chatter Questions, a Q&A feature that’s seamlessly integrated into Chatter. With Chatter Questions, users can ask questions and find answers without ever needing to leave Chatter.**

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=questions_portal_setup_enable.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check if your org is upgraded to Summer'16

Starting in Summer ’16, Chatter Answers isn’t available in new orgs. Instead, you can use Chatter Questions, a Q&A feature that’s seamlessly integrated into Chatter. With Chatter Questions, users can ask questions and find answers without ever needing to leave Chatter.

Help Link- https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=questions_portal_overview.htm

Comment: But my orgs is not new it is  old orgs. The article says it is not available in new orgs.

Comment: which instance your org is?

Comment: My orgs instance is NA10

Comment: Yes, your Org is upgraded to Summer'16, that is the reason you are not seeing chatter Answers.